# C#: Record and Playback GUI Events

Tags: c#, record

How can I record and playback mouse and keyboard events?

I need this to capture the user interactions with my application so that later on I can playback to see what the user did.

Comment: You might want to narrow the scope of the question.  As written, answers would either be book-length guides on how to write a library, or referrals to particular libraries.  Both are off topic for SO.  The answer depends upon your UI framework (WinForms / WPF / UWP / MAUI / Blazor / etc...), and in what form the collected data is to be used (as a replacement for [problem steps recorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/settings/how-to-use-problem-steps-recorder) or as general analytics).  There are also likely legal concerns depending on use and jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

There are literally hundreds of keyboard / mouse automation apps out there:

http://www.nonags.com/nonags/auto.html

I recommend [Do It Again](http://www.spacetornado.com/DoItAgain/) - its free, easy to use and works well, although if I remember correctly it has a quirk where it doesn't work particularly well over a remote desktop connection.

**UPDATE:** Just re-read the question, I dont think what you want is the ability to record keyboard / mouse actions, as its not guarenteed that the application will "keep up" with the mouse clicks (windows could open in slightly different places, or there could be a slight delay etc...)

What you want is some screen capture software.

Answer (score 0):

You should hook keyboard and mouse events, see [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) , [Low-Level Mouse Hook in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) or [Processing Global Windows Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2008/04/19/processing-global-mouse-and-keyboard-hooks-in-c/)